# Delete item from AJAX Toolkit ReorderList, position messed up

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, reorderlist

I have a `Reorderlist` which works pretty well. The only thing is that if I delete an `item` from the `list`, the item gets deleted in the `database` (just like it should) but the `positions` don't get `updated`. For instance, I have `five` items with positions `1` through `5`, I delete number `3` and the positions in the database are 1, 2, 4 and 5. I would want it to be 1 through 4 where 4 and 5 have moved up. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Is sort order stored in database?

Comment: There is a field named 'pos'. So yes...:-)

Comment: I believe you can add AFTER DELETE trigger to target table for adjusting order after row deletion